# G++ Inline Warning

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, inline, compiler-warnings

Here's some inlined code that's causing a warning using G++ (GCC) version 4.3.3.  I only get this problem on this (4.3.3) older GCC version on an ARM machine.  On an x86 machine running GCC 4.5.2, this problem is non-existent.  Unfortunately, I currently cannot update the ARM machine, but I am wondering if I should be concerned with the following error...

```
// myclass.h
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass() { Cleanup(); }
  void Cleanup();
};
inline void MyClass::Cleanup() {
  // do some minor cleanup here, GCC DOES inline this function
  // with -Winline, I see that no non-inline warnings are thrown
}
```

The problem is that I get the warning: "void MyClass::Cleanup() was used before it was declared inline"

Is this a warning I should concern myself with?  I've always inlined only in the function definition, essentially follow this (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/where-to-put-inline-keyword.html) "best practice."

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If your intention was to implement the `MyClass` member `Cleanup()` you may want to use the class name for resolving the inline. `inline void MyClass::Cleanup()` stands a much better chance of being what you're likely shooting for.

Comment: Whoops, forgot, that's actually in the code, but forgot to place that in my question... see above edit.

Comment: ... which is why its always a good idea to post **real** code.

Comment: ...which is how you get fired for violating NDAs and the such.  Plus, the code above is a simple, reproducable example of the error.  Sure I forgot a minor thing, but give me a break, it's been a LONG day.

Comment: Who said anything about posting *actual*, *protected*, *copy-written* code? You said it yourself: the above is a simple reproducible example. So the reason it wasn't what you intended was... because it was *too* simple? Give *me* a break. Posting *correct* concept code may be boring, but so is responding to *incorrect* concept code, only to find what you thought was an issue wasn't. Its once for you; we see it literally a hundred of times a day. So forgive me if I ask for the attention needed to avoid it. I'm sorry for your long day, mine wasn't any shorter, of that I can guarantee.

Comment: The code you posted didn't even compile originally, (see my first edit) then still didn't do what you meant it to (until your edit), so it reproduced sweet FA! You should **at least** have tried to compile what you posted. If you're going to ask dozens or hundreds of people to look at your question you should make the effort to get the question right! That means posting the relevant code. (Even now you've fixed it I still can't reproduce the warning with GCC 4.3.2)

Comment: Are you compiling with -O2, otherwise, I think inlining keywords are mostly ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is valid, and therefore the warning from the old G++ is bogus.

I don't know whether you should be concerned though. It's possible G++ does something bizarre based on its bogus belief that there's a problem in the code, but I doubt it - it probably works as expected and just emits the bogus warning.  It might fail to inline it into the destructor, but that's probably not a big deal, and `-Winline` seems to show that's not the case anyway.

Comment: Since the inline keyword solely functions as a hint, the worst case is that G++ doesn't see the hint, and is using a lowered heuristic for inlining.  I don't know about G++, but clang increases the maximum function size for inlining by 50% if the function is `inline`.  If inlining is of vital important, you can use a compiler extension.  G++ 4.3.3 supports `__attribute__((always_inline))` which would guarantee inlining.

Comment: It's not _solely_ a hint, it also allows functions to be defined in multiple translation units (without causing multiple definition errors) and some other semantic effects. It's only a hint as far as inlining by the optimiser goes, that's true.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with respect to the optimizer output, I should have been more clear.